# Exponential, cosine, sine

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, signal-processing

To begin with, I am sorry if my question is pathetic but I cannot understand why sometimes exponential involves cos and sometimes both cos and sin. I know that

```
    e^jωt = cos(ωt) + j sin(ωt)
```

but further reading the book that made me ask this question, I find that

```
    e^j(ωt + θ) = cos(ωt + θ)
```

Why sin is neglected in this case? Is this the same as the first?

Comment: Is it $$e^{i(\omega t+\theta)}$$?

Comment: If the book says that, then the book is wrong. But it is more likely that you missed some assumption concerning $\theta$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes that probably is $i$, I believe $j$ is used sometimes as the complex unit in physics especially electronics.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But even for a special $\theta$. Can the sine actually be $0$ for every $t$ (which we need to make the equation valid) ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, yes, but I assume "i" is replaced with "j" in signal processing in order to avoid confusing it with current.

Comment: @Peter No, it cannot. On the other hand, in your question you did not say that this was supposed to hold for every $t$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am not the asker :)

Comment: @Peter Oops! I hadn't made this mistake in a long time!

Answer (score 1):

There is probably something in the problem that leads to taking the real part.  Engineering books are often sloppy on this, or you may have overlooked it.  The equation as written is incorrect, but with a real part sign around the left it is correct.  The use of $j$ instead of $i$ is common in engineering because they use $i$ for electrical current.